# Fault-finding - DataGridView DataBindingComplete is unable to set column widths

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I get a NullReferenceError when setting the column width when DataBindingComplete fires in a DataGridView. the DGV uses a DataTable which is pre-prepared in Step(1), and then set to .DataSource in Step(2). Step (3) is to format the column widths, because that can't be done until after DataBindingComplete.

Simplified code:

```
//STEP 2/3: Move data into the listBox
public void setupListBox() {
    m_Initialized=true;             //DataBindingComplete now unsuppressed
    listBox.DataSource=m_datatable; //Next, "Data Binding Complete" will fire
}

//STEP 3/3: Data finished being moved, do col widths and headertext
private void listBox_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e) {
    if(!m_Initialized) return;  //Doesn't work. This still gets called multiple times

    DataGridViewColumn lCol;
    for(byte lColIndex = 0;lColIndex<m_cols.Count();lColIndex++) {
        lCol=listBox.Columns[lColIndex];
        lCol.HeaderText=m_datatable.Columns[lColIndex].Caption;  //apply header texts from datatable to the GridView, which stupidly doesn't pick them up

        Debug.WriteLine(lColIndex.ToString()+": "+m_cols[lColIndex].name + 
            "CurrentWidth:" +lCol.Width + ", New: " +m_cols[lColIndex].width); //Everything is as expected

        lCol.Width=m_cols[lColIndex].width; // ExcepttionNullReference here
        //Note that the Debug.WriteLine above proves that lCol.Width exists and lCol is valid (etc)
    }
}
```

After DataBindingComplete suppression is turned off (m_Initialized=true) then DataBindingComplete is called twice*, with the e.ListChangedType value of "Reset". (See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.listchangedtype(v=vs.110).aspx ).
* I wish there was a callback for listBox.DataSource=m_datatable that could be caught when the listBox.DataSource finishes being set. DataBindingComplete is too spurious.

[Note: The reason I loop through the cols instead of using forEach is that I have to record the index of the first visible column (so I can set SelectedCells later), but forEach doesn't give me index numbers. The error actually occurs on the 5th column, which is the first one that gets a Width set - others are either visible=false, or DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill).]

StackOverflow is full of threads where people are trying to deal with repeated firings of DataBindingComplete. Also, lots of people try to setup the widths before DataBindingComplete; but I'm not making that mistake. And, I'm only getting two firings of DataBindingComplete after my suppression technique (many others get 5 or 10 firings). But nothing answers the question of why would the widths not be available AFTER DataBindingComplete?

Comment: I've looked at DataMember, which is good for reducing the number of DataBindingComplete calls, but, I don't think I should be using it here; there's no single "table" name to set it to.

Comment: Context: This code is in a UserControl [ucListAndFilter] that is used on multiple forms. The form setups the DataTable (Step 1), then calls ucListAndFilter.setupListBox (step 2) which triggers DataBindingComplete (Step 3). On frmMain it works fine with 116 list items - i.e., it sets the column widths to custom values during DataBindingComplete. A similar (but smaller) dataset is shown on frmTrack (just 1 item), but, the error occurs there.

Comment: On frmTracks, there are two instances of ucListAndFilter. The first one works (listRelated) and correctly displays two items with the columns being set according to m_cols[lColIndex].width.

But the second one (listFoundIn) gets errors with setting the ColWidths, and, it calls the same code in the same way. I've deleted and recreated the object in Design mode, and, tried copying-and-renaming listRelated just in case there are any properties that need setting (there aren't).

Comment: If I set the column widths EARLIER in the form constructor, then, it works with no error. I thought maybe I was going to have to use a timer, to make sure the DataGridView had called DataBindingsComplete enough times before setting widths. But the opposite was true. I don't know why. So there's a chance that this error will re-occur if the volumes of data are different. Very hard to fault-find without knowing why col widths aren't accessible :-(